# Testing locally GAE-python27-django projects

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nose

I'm triyng to tests some GAE models with `nose` and `noseGAE` plugin.

The tutorials show how to run the test using the `webapp` framework setup like in this tutorial
http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/ . But since I'm using django, my `main.py` is:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
app = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

When I try to run nose:

```
$ nosetests --with-gae
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\core.py", line 135, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\config.py", line 338, in configure
    self.plugins.configure(options, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\plugins\manager.py", line 284, in configure
    cfg(options, config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\plugins\manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\nose\plugins\manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\nosegae.py", line 80, in configure
ImportError: No module named dev_appserver
```

I thought that it was because the django dependencies, bu next i tried to run a single file:

```
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

class TestServicios(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUP(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then:

```
$ python test_models.py
```

And:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import testbed
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

GAE info
 release: 1.7.3
 runtime: python27

Somebody knows what is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Setting_Up_a_Testing_Framework).  It shows an example how you can write a testrunner.py to load your test class, so you can have a mini test framework.  Specifically, the following code is what you are looking for:

```
sys.path.insert(0, sdk_path)
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

sdk_path is where your google_appengine sdk is located at.  For instance, it could be /usr/local/google_appengine on linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using django, I'd recommend using the django test infrastructure instead of nose-gae.

Comment: Have you experiment troubles of some kind with the datastore or any other service working on django?

Comment: There's a bit of pain when django models don't match the GAE native db models, like working with transactions.  Also, I'm using django-nonrel with the HRD.  Your results may vary with pure django on CloudSQL.